# How can I use the returned value of an array ("right" and "left" in my case) from one function( "extract") to another function("BinToDec")?

Tags: c

```
void main()
{   
    extract();
    BinToDec();
}

int BinToDec()
{
    int decimal = 0, base = 1, rem, num;
    int x = atoi(right);

    num = x;
    while (x != 0)
    {
        rem = x % 10;
        decimal = decimal + rem*base;
        x = x / 10;
        base = base * 2;
    }

    printf("the decimal equivalent of the binary number %d is: %d", num, decimal);
}

void extract()
{
    int i;
    char foo[29];

    printf("Enter the number and opperator\n");
    scanf("%s",foo);

    int index;
    int len = strlen(foo);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (foo[i] == '+' || foo[i] == '-' || foo[i] == '*' || foo[i] == '/' || foo[i] == '%')
        {
            char op = foo[i];
            printf("%c", op);
            index = i;
        }
    }

    char left[14];
    for (int j = 0; j < index; j++)
    {
        left[j] = foo[j]);
        printf("%c", left[j]);
    }

    char right[14];
    for (int k = index + 1; k < len; k++)
    {
        right[k] = foo[k];
        printf("%c", right[k]);
    }    
}
```

}

My intention in this code is to use the values that are appended in the array "left" and "right" from the array "foo" in the function "extract" and pass it to the function "BinToDec" and store the returned value in some variable called "decimal". This is because, later on, I want to use the returned value from BinToDec to some other function I am working on.

Comment: Where is `right` in your code? Also you have an extraneous bracket on line 44. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: In the process of trying to format your code, a number of errors that popped up that would render this code not runnable. Please make sure that when you post a code snippet, it is one that we can actually paste into a code editor and run. (And in the future, I highly recommend keeping your code formatting clean and consistent so these errors get recognized immediately.)

Comment: You can create a struct containing your parsed values, and return it from your extract function, make those variables which you want shared global, or refactor you parameters for your methods to accept pointers of the data you want shared.

Comment: The reason you cannot use variable right in BinToDec is due to scope. Variable right has scope only in your extract method. Therefore, you will need to refactor your method signatures, or make the variables you want to reuse in other functions global

Comment: @ Govind Parmar  and @Abinon47 sorry for the bad indentation and error. The variable right is found in extract in the second for loop.

Comment: Consider writing functions with explicit arguments and non `void` return type (so giving some genuine result). The result could be a pointer. BTW `main` is not allowed to return `void`. See some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site, and read a good C programming book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//you use two  shared global variables for example
int leftop,rightop;
void extract();
//make the bintodec takes one side as input & returns the value so its more generic and you call inside the extract function for example
int BinToDec(char * operand);
int main()
{
extract();
}

// now the function bintoDec takes char* something like 1111 & turns it into decimal 15 & return it 
//so it doesn't really care whether its the right of the left operand 
// it just return the binary value of the decimal you gave it to it
int BinToDec(char * operand)
{

int decimal=0, base=1, rem, num;
int x = atoi(operand);
num = x;
while(x != 0)
{
    rem = x % 10;
    decimal = decimal + rem*base;
    x = x / 10;
    base = base*2;
}
printf("the decimal equivalent of the binary number %d is: %d\n", num,
decimal);
  //here the returned value here we assign to the leftop and rightop depens on the input
 return decimal;
}
void extract(){

int i;
char foo[29];
printf("Enter the number and opperator\n");
scanf("%s",foo);

int index;
int len = strlen(foo);

for (i=0; i < len; i++)
{
if(foo[i] == '+' || foo[i] == '-' || foo[i] == '*' || foo[i] == '/' ||foo[i] == '%'){
   char op = foo[i];
   printf("%c", op);
   index = i;
    }
}
char left[14];
for(int j=0; j < index; j++){
   left[j] = foo[j];
   printf("%c", left[j]);
}

 //now you can get both values of left & right operands like this 
 // now after we split the operands we call BinToDec with the left operand & give the returns value
//which represents the binary value of that left operand to the "leftop" global variable so you can use it in your other functions
leftop = BinToDec(left);
char right[14];
i=0;
//side note : your code had right[k]=foo[k] which is wrong because right array starts from 0 to 13 & k can go till 27 
  // which will cause you an error


for(int k=index + 1; k < len; k++){
   right[i] = foo[k];
   printf("%c", right[i]);
   i++;
}

 //now same thing to the right operand we call the function we gave it the binary value & it  returns us the decimal value & we assign it this time to the rightop global variable for other uses outside this function
rightop=BinToDec(right);

}
```